# Android: adb install apk fail

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I just started mobile development a few weeks ago. I am having one problem when I am trying to install the application to my phone(Huawei phone) with "adb install app/build/outputs/apk/newApk.apk". The first time I run this command, I get this error:

```
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install app/build/outputs/apk/newApk.apk: (my branch)
```

When I try again, it is stuck at Performing Streamed Install.
I am not sure if the problem is with my phone model or adb. I tried "adb (deviceId) install app/build/outputs/apk/newApk.apk" with options like -t, -r, and still without success. I also do not have the application installed on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running it on an android emulator or try a different phone

Comment: Isn't there any other options other than running on an android emulator?
And I do not have any spare phone.

Comment: i think you can use external emulators... but i never had the need for one so don't  know much... you should look it up on internet

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given all the permission on phone, USB debugging is enabled, Install via USB is enabled.

Try, adb devices. Phone should show your phone on terminal

OR,
Try below steps if it works
Try below steps:
1. disconnect phone
2. turn Off “USB Debugging” and turn it on
3. connect the device again

OR, 
Last thing you can try is move your apk file to some other location and try to install from that location(as sometime it happens because of folder permission or corrupt folder).

Comment: Thank you Swetank for all these options. I tried options 1 and 2 before, to no avail.
I just tried option 3, it does not work either. Can it be corrupted apk?

Comment: To check that apk is corrupted or not, install same apk on your emulator via adb install and check if that works.